# Offer someone something

Tags: gerunds

I know we can say offer somebody something. In this case can we use gerund insteas of “something” like

> He offered me living together.

Isn’t living together noun? If it is noun can it be correct if it is not correct does this sentence have a meaning?

Comment: It's not correct English. It's not even easy to understand what you mean. If you mean that someone offered you the opportunity to live with them, you need to phrase it differently. Even then, it's ambiguous. It might mean in the same house or the same bed. If you look up **living** and **together** as parts of speech, you will find the answer to your other question.

Comment: @RonaldSole *"live together"* is quite common and means  *"share a home and have a sexual relationship"*... I don't see anything wrong with *"He offered me to live together"* or *"He offered me to move in with him"*

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it either but as someone who lived together in a big house with the person I later married and with several other individuals whom I didn't marry, I merely argue that the phrase can be interpreted in more than one way (not that I would make a big deal of it).